# Schema.org markup for Custom Post Archives and Custom Taxonomy Archives?

Tags: schema.org

I am using Schema.org (JSON-LD) for Custom Post Type - Movies.

I am confused about which one of them ([`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList), [`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage) or [`Collection`](https://bib.schema.org/Collection)) would be most appropriate for Archive Page (All Movies) and Taxonomy Archive Pages (e.g. Genre: Action).

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283780/1591669) help?

Comment: According to that answer, archive page should be marked with (CollectionPage, mainentity, Collection) since its all about one particular type of things. List would be more relevant for something like Top 100 movies. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: There is not necessarily a clear difference between these two types. For something like a blog about movies, I would use `ItemList` for the archive/taxonomy/category pages -- it’s just *a list* of `BlogPosting`s (e.g., ordered by posting date), not an actual collection I created. For something like a personal site showing photos of my DVD collection, I would use `Collection`. And if I show my movie collection ordered by my own rating, I would use `ItemList` and `Collection` together.

Comment: The intent is to indicate SearchBots that all the items on the page belong together. It seems both options give similar results in this case. I will go ahead with ItemList option since it comes default with the plugin I am using for displaying archives instead of reinventing the wheel.