# What is the Schema.org markup for a group of Things?

Tags: schema.org

I understand how to do schema markup for a specific thing (a shoe, for example).  But how do you do the schema markup for a group of things?  "Men's Running Shoes" for example.

Comment: Google recommends ItemList of urls https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings

Answer (score 3):

A page that is primarily about one thing:

[`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) [`Thing`](https://schema.org/Thing)

A page that is primarily about a list of things:

[`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage) [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) [`ItemList`](https://schema.org/ItemList)

A page that is primarily about a collection of things:

[`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage) [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) [`Collection`](https://schema.org/Collection)

A page that is about multiple things (where a list/collection isn’t needed or doesn’t make sense):

[`CollectionPage`](https://schema.org/CollectionPage) [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart) [`Thing`](https://schema.org/Thing)