# How to use Microdata to represent similar products on the ItemPage?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to use Microdata to define my website using the Schema.org definitions.

Below is my current HTML markup:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
<link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/i/10" />

<main role="main">

    <!-- Show the main product of the page -->           
    <div itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="My Main Product 10 Name" />
        <!-- ... more properties that describes current product -->   
    </div>


    <!-- List of 10 similar product the current product being viewed -->
    <div class="list-related-products">

        <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Related Product 20 Name" />
            <meta itemprop="url" content="https://example.com/i/20" />
            <div itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/i/10" />
            </div>
            <!-- ... more properties -->   
        </div>

        <!-- ... more products -->   
    </div>
</main>

</body>
```

When I validate the code using [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/), the similar products section shows up as a separate nodes and not part of the [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage).

[image]

How can I list the related similar products correctly under the current product being defined?

Comment: 1) Is there a reason for using `isSimilarTo` inside the related product to reference the URL of the primary product? Or aren’t the first and third `Product` items supposed to be the same? 2) Instead of posting the full HTML document, please [edit] your question to make it a minimal example that only shows the relevant parts (e.g., here you could exclude the header, the footer, and the website; and you could use a `div` for the `ItemPage` so you don’t have to include the `html`/`head`/`body` elements).

Comment: @unor The example above is showing full product details for a product with the id of 10 (example.com/i/10). At the bottom of the page, I am listing similar products, in this case, its a product with the id of 10 (example.com/i/20). I have updated the question as per your instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1: nesting

You can add `isSimilarTo` inside the primary product:

```html
<article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h2 itemprop="name">Product 10</h2>

  <aside>
    <article itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <h3 itemprop="name">Product 20</h3>
    </article>

    <article itemprop="isSimilarTo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <h3 itemprop="name">Product 30</h3>
    </article>
  </aside>

</article>
```

#### Solution 2: `itemref`

If you can’t nest the similar products under the HTML element for the primary product, you could use Microdata’s `itemref` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21161277/1591669)).

#### Solution 3: ID

(You should only go this way if solutions 1 or 2 aren’t possible, as not all consumers will support this solution 3.)

Similar to what you’re currently using, you can give the primary product an URI as identifier (with Microdata’s `itemid` attribute) and reference this URI as value for the `isSimilarTo` inside the similar products.

```html
<article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemid="https://example.com/i/10#this">
  <h2 itemprop="name">Product 10</h2>
</article>

<aside>
  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <h3 itemprop="name">Product 20</h3>
      <link itemprop="isSimilarTo" href="https://example.com/i/10#this" />
  </article>

  <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <h3 itemprop="name">Product 30</h3>
      <link itemprop="isSimilarTo" href="https://example.com/i/10#this" />
  </article>
</aside>
```

Comment: Of course, this is the right answer :) Thank you. I want to list products on a WebPage what property do I use? I can't find a property that I can use. That would be a list of a featured items not related to the current product.

Comment: @Junior: You mean for something like a category page? See [What is the Schema.org markup for a group of Things?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53266384/1591669)

Comment: I actually can't seem to get solution 2 to work. I initially got solution 1 to work, then found out that the related items must be placed outside of the Product scope. I updated my question with the attempt to use the `itemref` which does not seems to make the related items part of the product as "similar" items

Comment: @Junior: I rolled back [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58261093/5), as the scope of questions shouldn’t be changed. Please create a separate question about the `itemref` issue.

Comment: As per your suggestion, a new question was added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58273988/how-to-use-microdata-to-to-reference-similar-product-that-are-listed-outside-of